# JQUI datepicker changing month or year resets after selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm experiencing an issue using the JQUI datepicker where I have a from and to text field. Picking a from date, auto selects the next field using the `onClose` function.

When trying to change the month or year from the drop down boxes in the ***to*** text field the datepicker popup gets reset and the user has to re-select the month or year. This only appears to happen on the ***to*** field.

Am I doing something wrong in the code to cause this behaviour? I've noticed this in Chrome and Firefox on Windows.

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fWwR4/)**

**CODE**

```
$('#sfd_start').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+2y",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $('#sfd_end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
        $('#sfd_end').focus();
    }
});

$('#sfd_end').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    maxDate: "+2y"
});
```

***EDIT:*** There doesn't seem to be an issue if the datepicker is ***not*** auto opened after selecting a from date if that helps narrow it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a timing issue. Change your onClose function to:

```
onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    $('#sfd_end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#sfd_end').focus();
    }, 100);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fWwR4/7/)**